# Can't get rid of mysterious outdated git installation on OS X

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, git

I'm trying to update my git installation to the latest version. I'm having trouble getting rid of the old version, which the `git` command is still referencing:

```
$ git --version
git version 1.6.3.2
```

This is weird because:

```
$ which git
/usr/local/bin/git
```

and:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/git --version
git version 1.8.4
```

I didn't use MacPorts to install the old one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aliases will resolve first, so if you alias 'git' to someplace, then BASH will go to the alias location, which can be different from the first place that git appears on the PATH, which is what  `which git` shows you.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following:

```
hash -r
```

or alternatively, close your Terminal session (completely, with <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>) and then reopen it. I'm suspecting you've been using the same session for a long time, and the shell still has the old location of the `git` binary in its path hash (hence the name of the command). Rehashing (the `-r` option) or restarting the shell will clear everything out and reload it.

Comment: Tried that first thing. Didn't help.

Comment: that's strange - did you run `hash -r` or restart Terminal?

Comment: what shell are you using?

Comment: I had tried restarting the Terminal many times over the course of the last hour or so. I didn't know about `hash -r`. I'm using bash.

Comment: strange indeed...

Comment: Yeah. I want my evening back. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I just went to each directory in my PATH and looked for the old version of git. I found it in ~/bin. Removed it and now I'm good to go. I still don't understand why `which` is finding the new one but the `git` command was finding the old one.

Comment: see my answer below...

Comment: Thanks. I did try that but it didn't help. I had to hunt down and remove the old one. Still confused though.

Comment: Is it possible you had aliased git to ~/bin/git ?